# ActionCable with rails 5.1.3 not able to upgrade websocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, real-time, actioncable

The real time notification with ActionCable works fine in my development environment which uses puma server.

However it is not working while I deploy it in production. I am getting these errors.

```
I, [2017-08-29T12:19:15.074453 #4737]  INFO -- : [9850bab1-05b1-4844-b6f2-857061c20800] Started GET "/cable" for 202.166.198.221 at 2017-08-29 12:19:15 +0000
I, [2017-08-29T12:19:15.076219 #4737]  INFO -- : [9850bab1-05b1-4844-b6f2-857061c20800] Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 202.166.198.221 at 2017-08-29 12:19:15 +0000
E, [2017-08-29T12:19:15.076462 #4737] ERROR -- : [9850bab1-05b1-4844-b6f2-857061c20800] Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
I, [2017-08-29T12:19:15.076658 #4737]  INFO -- : [9850bab1-05b1-4844-b6f2-857061c20800] Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 202.166.198.221 at 2017-08-29 12:19:15 +0000
I, [2017-08-29T12:19:18.613916 #4737]  INFO -- : [15f6fde7-2329-4e77-b97b-b7b409f9ae9a] Started GET "/cable" for 202.166.198.221 at 2017-08-29 12:19:18 +0000
I, [2017-08-29T12:19:18.615298 #4737]  INFO -- : [15f6fde7-2329-4e77-b97b-b7b409f9ae9a] Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 202.166.198.221 at 2017-08-29 12:19:18 +0000
```

I never got "Failed to upgrade to WebSocket" in my development server. Googled a lot but none of the solutions worked.

cable.yml prod setting

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Do I have to change anything in nginx.conf coz lots of other posts are suggesting to do make some change. I did it, but didn't work.